Spring boot @KafkaListener not listening to the topic name using SPEL as mentioned in framework
I have developed a kafka listener. Here are my different classes designed :
Class KafkaProperties {
    
    public String topicZZZ;
    public String groupId;
    ...
}


Class KafkaConfig {     

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public KafkaProperties populateKafkaProperties() {
        KafkaProperties obj = new KafkaProperties();
        obj.settopicZZZ("kafkaTopicName");
        
        return obj;
    }
}

Class B {

    @Autowired
    KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;
    
    @Autowired
    KafkaProperties kafkaProps;
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"#{'kafkaProps.topicZZZ'}" }, 
                   groupId = "#{'kafkaProps.groupId'}", containerFactory = "onlineKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeOnlineMessages() {
    
        log.info();
        
    }
}

When I am starting my application there is no error but it seems it is not picking up the topic name as I am unable to consume any messages.
I can see this line in the logs :
Subscribed to topic(s): kafkaProps.topicZZZ

But when I pass the topic name from properties file using the below in @kafkaListener I am getting the correct topic name.
@KafkaListener(topics = {"${kafka.topicNamefromPropFile}"  }, 
               groupId = "${kafka.groupid}",

So it is clear that the below is not working :
@KafkaListener(topics = {"#{'kafkaProps.topicZZZ'}" }, 

I have followed the semantics  from spring docs
There it is mentioned like we can use like below , but this is throwing error related to parsing spel expression :
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{someBean.someProperty}",
    groupId = "#{someBean.someProperty}.group")

EDIT : I can see the ConsumerConfig values getting loaded correctly, if anyone needs to see any property from there please let me know.
Can someone help me to use the topic name properly in the listener.

When the application is up it will log the consumer properties, can u please show them ?

@RyuzakiL : Which property(ies) you want please tell me as the list is huge, In that I can see bootstrap server loaded correctly, i can see the group id value is correct.. etc

Your #{'kafkaProps.topicZZZ'} expression is resolved just to the plain string because of those quotes.
That #{someBean.someProperty} expression from the doc means: find a someBean in the application context and call its getSomeProperty() method.
In your case it look like you thought it is about a property you have just autowired into your class with @KafkaListener.
See if you can determine KafkaProperties bean name and use exactly that one in this SpEL expression and without quotes, of course.

By changing the Bean creation method name resolved the issue for me.
I have changed populateKafkaProperties() to kafkaProps() which resolved my issue.
And in consumer now I can use like below :
@KafkaListener(topics = {"#{kafkaProps.topicZZZ}"}, 
               groupId = "#{kafkaProps.groupId}")

Thanks to Artem Bilan for giving me some directions.
